# Create Dynamic High chart On Group By Data Set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a below dataset:

```
var data = [{
    "France": {
        "val1": [10, 20, 30, 40],
        "val2": [10, 20, 30, 4]
    },
    "Croatia": {
        "val1": [50, 60, 70, 80],
        "val2": [50, 60, 70, 8]}
}];
```

It's a group by data and my target is to create two dynamic high chart on the dataset given above. So one chart would be created on **France** dataset and other one is **Croatia** with their respective values **val1** and **val2**. I was trying something as follows:

```js
var data = [{
    "France": {
        "val1": [10, 20, 30, 40],
        "val2": [10, 20, 30, 4]
    },
    "Croatia": {
        "val1": [50, 60, 70, 80],
        "val2": [50, 60, 70, 8]}
}];

for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
console.log(data[i].France);
console.log(data[i].Croatia);
console.log(data.length);

var val = i + 1;
var containerName = 'container' + val;

console.log(containerName);

Highcharts.chart(containerName, {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'France',
        data: data[0].France.val2

    }, {
        name: 'Croatia',
        data: data[0].Croatia.val2

    }]
});
}
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container1">
</div>

<div id="container2">
</div>
```

Is it possible to create two different charts according to their respective data set? Here's a `Js` fiddle that I tried but failed: [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaL8b1ym)

Comment: `i <= data.length` should be `i < data.length`, because of zero based indices.

Comment: But the above doesn't render as expected. Any suggestion @Nina Scholz?

Comment: whta intermediate result do you expect?

Comment: I want to generate two dynamic high charts on two datasets, one for France  `"France": { "val1": [10, 20, 30, 40], "val2": [10, 20, 30, 4] }` and another for Croatia `"Croatia": { "val1": [50, 60, 70, 80], "val2": [50, 60, 70, 8]}`. Is it possible @Nina Scholz?

Comment: what do expect as rendering?

Comment: First chart will be for France, in series options in the chart will be val1, val2. Same for Croatia in second chart with its val1 and val2.